# How to create a new MongoDB collection with laravel-mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using `laravel-mongodb`(https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to manipulate mongodb data.

How to create a new  MongoDB collection with laravel-mongodb?

for example:

```
public function test()
{
    $newArtciels = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('articles')->where('status', '1')->get();

    //I want to ceate a new collection `new_artciels`, and save `$newArtciels` into `new_artciels`,how to write next?
}
```

**Question:**
I want to ceate a new collection `new_artciels`, and save `$newArtciels` into `new_artciels`,what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class new_artciels extends Eloquent
{
  protected $collection = 'new_artciels';}
```

Controller

```
use App\new_artciels;
```

this should work for  you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use this to crate collections

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->createCollection("logger");
```

Refer document : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.createcollection.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create collect in first time. when insert first data in mongo collection, it just create and store data according to your data.

In laravel framework best way use `jenssegers` package. U can find it documentation from [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

It so easy to use. just add mongo db connection to config like bellow

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
    'options' => [
        'appname' => 'homestead',
    ],
],
```

After that extend your model from jenssegers model like bellow

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'books';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
}
```

And finally create(or save if exists collection) like bellow:

```
$book = new Book();
$book->title = 'A Game of Thrones';
$book->save();
```

It so Easy!!!!! Enjoy :)